# How can I do a Many-to-Many where clause in Sails.js/Waterline?

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js

I have this code

```
Image.find({ tags: {id: 3}}).exec(console.log);
```

which is wrong, but my intention is to find all images that have the `tag id 3`.

An image can have many tags, and many images can be tagged with the same tag (many-to-many).

Model code.

**Image**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        tags: {
            collection: 'Tag',
            via: 'images'
        }
    }
};
```

**Tag**

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        images: {
            collection: 'Image',
            via: 'tags'
        }
    }
};
```

I don't want to use SQL raw queries, nor I want to use `N+1` queries to populate everything.

I also tried using `.populate()` by using `Image.find(3).populate("images")...` but it will only populate the images, but each image won't have tags, so this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code.

Below code may still do N+1 queries internally.
Best way to check will be to enable query logs in database.

Note: I haven't checked code for syntax errors.

```
function findImagesByTagId(tagId, callback) {
  Tag.findOne(tagId)
    .populate("images")
    .exec(function(err, tag) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      if (!tag) {
        return callback(new Error('tag not found: ' + tagId));
      }
      // Collect all image ids
      var imageIds = _.map(tag.images, 'id');

      Image.find(imageIds)
        .populate('tags')
        .exec(callback);
    });
}
```